# admin/login route is going post page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my routes.rb

```
  get '/admin/login' => 'admin/sessions#new'
  get '/admin/logout' => 'admin/sessions#destroy'
  get '/admin' => 'admin/dashboard#index'

  get 'blog' => 'blogs#index'
  get ':id' => 'posts#show'
  get 'posts/:id' => redirect('%{id}')
  get 'blog/:id' => 'blogs#show'
  get 'category/:id' => 'posts#index'

  namespace :admin do
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :login, only: [:index, :edit]
    resources :categories
    resources :admins, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :dashboard, only:[:index]
    resources :settings, only:[:new, :create, :edit, :update]
    resources :posts
    resources :blogs
  end

  resources :home, only:[:index]
  resources :posts, only:[:index, :show]
  resources :blogs, only:[:index, :show]
```

when i try go to the /admin/login page it is seems like post page or something. but i can see the login form. just it is not admin page (i mean there is no my admin css or something it is seems like admin login form in my normal front end post page. and when i try login with my username and password it is giving this error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Admin::Posts#new
```

then im deleting this part from routes.rb

```
  get 'blog' => 'blogs#index'
  get ':id' => 'posts#show'
  get 'posts/:id' => redirect('%{id}')
  get 'blog/:id' => 'blogs#show'
  get 'category/:id' => 'posts#index'
```

then i can go to the admin page. then im pasting this part again and still can use admin panel with no errors i dont understand.

can someone help? (sorry for my english)

here is the rake routes

```
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
                 root GET    /                                    home#index
          admin_login GET    /admin/login(.:format)               admin/sessions#new
         admin_logout GET    /admin/logout(.:format)              admin/sessions#destroy
                admin GET    /admin(.:format)                     admin/dashboard#index
                 blog GET    /blog(.:format)                      blogs#index
                      GET    /:id(.:format)                       posts#show
                      GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                 redirect(301, %{id})
                      GET    /blog/:id(.:format)                  blogs#show
                      GET    /category/:id(.:format)              posts#index
       admin_sessions POST   /admin/sessions(.:format)            admin/sessions#create
    new_admin_session GET    /admin/sessions/new(.:format)        admin/sessions#new
        admin_session DELETE /admin/sessions/:id(.:format)        admin/sessions#destroy
    admin_login_index GET    /admin/login(.:format)               admin/login#index
     edit_admin_login GET    /admin/login/:id/edit(.:format)      admin/login#edit
     admin_categories GET    /admin/categories(.:format)          admin/categories#index
                      POST   /admin/categories(.:format)          admin/categories#create
   new_admin_category GET    /admin/categories/new(.:format)      admin/categories#new
  edit_admin_category GET    /admin/categories/:id/edit(.:format) admin/categories#edit
       admin_category GET    /admin/categories/:id(.:format)      admin/categories#show
                      PATCH  /admin/categories/:id(.:format)      admin/categories#update
                      PUT    /admin/categories/:id(.:format)      admin/categories#update
                      DELETE /admin/categories/:id(.:format)      admin/categories#destroy
         admin_admins GET    /admin/admins(.:format)              admin/admins#index
                      POST   /admin/admins(.:format)              admin/admins#create
      new_admin_admin GET    /admin/admins/new(.:format)          admin/admins#new
     edit_admin_admin GET    /admin/admins/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/admins#edit
          admin_admin PATCH  /admin/admins/:id(.:format)          admin/admins#update
                      PUT    /admin/admins/:id(.:format)          admin/admins#update
                      DELETE /admin/admins/:id(.:format)          admin/admins#destroy
admin_dashboard_index GET    /admin/dashboard(.:format)           admin/dashboard#index
       admin_settings POST   /admin/settings(.:format)            admin/settings#create
    new_admin_setting GET    /admin/settings/new(.:format)        admin/settings#new
   edit_admin_setting GET    /admin/settings/:id/edit(.:format)   admin/settings#edit
        admin_setting PATCH  /admin/settings/:id(.:format)        admin/settings#update
                      PUT    /admin/settings/:id(.:format)        admin/settings#update
          admin_posts GET    /admin/posts(.:format)               admin/posts#index
                      POST   /admin/posts(.:format)               admin/posts#create
       new_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/new(.:format)           admin/posts#new
      edit_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id/edit(.:format)      admin/posts#edit
           admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)           admin/posts#show
                      PATCH  /admin/posts/:id(.:format)           admin/posts#update
                      PUT    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)           admin/posts#update
                      DELETE /admin/posts/:id(.:format)           admin/posts#destroy
          admin_blogs GET    /admin/blogs(.:format)               admin/blogs#index
                      POST   /admin/blogs(.:format)               admin/blogs#create
       new_admin_blog GET    /admin/blogs/new(.:format)           admin/blogs#new
      edit_admin_blog GET    /admin/blogs/:id/edit(.:format)      admin/blogs#edit
           admin_blog GET    /admin/blogs/:id(.:format)           admin/blogs#show
                      PATCH  /admin/blogs/:id(.:format)           admin/blogs#update
                      PUT    /admin/blogs/:id(.:format)           admin/blogs#update
                      DELETE /admin/blogs/:id(.:format)           admin/blogs#destroy
           home_index GET    /home(.:format)                      home#index
                posts GET    /posts(.:format)                     posts#index
                 post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                 posts#show
                blogs GET    /blogs(.:format)                     blogs#index
                      GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)                 blogs#show
```

Comment: run `rake routes` and post the output

Comment: okey here is the routes

Comment: You have 2 paths for `get "admin/login"` which means the second one will win.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is on these two lines.

```
get ':id' => 'posts#show'
get 'posts/:id' => redirect('%{id}')
```

Try this

```
get 'posts/:id' => 'posts#show'
```

Comment: but i want like localhost:3000/this-is-post not like localhost:3000/post/this-is-post